# How can I access individual entries in a bytes object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, web.py

I'm trying to get input from an html form using a js script and pass it to a web.py controller with the following two pieces of code:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $("#register-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postregistration',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
         }
     });
});
```

and

```
class PostRegistration:
def POST(self):
    data = web.data()
    return data.username
```

also here's the field im trying to access

```
<div class="form-group label-static is-empty">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a username" />
</div>
```

The data being passed by the script is the same format as shown on the jquery api page and the python code is the same as all the example code I've seen but the code throws a "500 - Internal Server Error" which says "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'username'"

How can I access individual values of the serialize method's output?

Edit: this isn't a duplicate because i'm trying to get post data without using json but that's fine. it looks like the issue here is that these two pieces of code:

```
class PostRegistration:
def POST(self):
    data = web.data()
    return data.username
```

and

```
class PostRegistration:
def POST(self):
    data = web.data().username
    return data
```

are not equivalent. the first throws a 500 error and the second does what i want. can anyone explain why?

Comment: I realize I'm guessing here... really not very familiar to Python. But what if you serialize your data this way: `JSON.stringify $("#register-form").serializeArray())` and server side something like `data = json.loads(request.form.get('data'))`. I guess that requires you to import json too.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a duplicate, but I can't do anything about that...  You're sending serialized data (NOT JSON), which will have the form 'username=John&other=foo'. Typically, you'd read in using web.py as `username = web.input().username`, as it will handle the serialization properly.  If you want to do it yourself, try `urlparse.parse_qs(web.data())['username']`.

Comment: Check your code... they are equivalent and you should be getting ServerError 500 for both. web.data() returns a str in python2, and a bytes object in python3... neither of which have a attribute 'username', so your POST() will be throwing AttributeError exception.